# findViewById in fragment in android

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I’m trying to initialize ViewPager in Fragment (`ViewPager pager = fragmentNews.getPager()`), but it’s still null:

My fragment:

```
import android.os.Bundle;

import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;


public class NewsFragment extends Fragment {

    private ViewPager pager;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_news, container, false);
        pager = (ViewPager) view.findViewById(R.id.sliding_pager);
        return view;
    }



    public ViewPager setAdapterForPager(PagerAdapter adapter){
        pager.setAdapter(adapter);
        return pager;
    }

    public ViewPager getPager() {
        return pager;
    }
}
```

Here is my MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {
...

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
...
FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
fm.beginTransaction().add(R.id.container_for_fragments, fragmentNews).commit();
pagerAdapter = new MyFragmentPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());


ViewPager pager = fragmentNews.getPager();

pager.setAdapter(pagerAdapter);
...
```

fragment_news.xml:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="100"
    tools:context=".fragments.NewsFragment">


    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/sliding_pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="30" />

...

</LinearLayout>
```

But in NewsFragment.java pager remains null. So after launching I have got RuntimeException, mistake in row:

pager.setAdapter(pagerAdapter); in MainActivity.java

Without trying to initialize the ViewPager, the app works fine.

Comment: You are not showing us where `fragmentNews.getPager();` has been initialized.

Comment: Are you trying to nest ViewPagers? Because you're defining a ViewPager within each page.

Comment: @Gi0rgi0s : I am putting one ViewPager into a Fragment. In the fragment in method `onCreateView()` I'm trying to initialize it (but it's still null). And launching this Fragment from MainActivity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely, the `onCreateView` of the fragment hasn't been executed yet. It takes time adding a Fragment to your Activity. You can't assume it happened right after adding it.

What you can do is overwrite `onViewCreated` in the Fragment that notifies the Activity in some way that it is created.

Also, where is `fragmentNews` coming from? you do a `new NewsFragment()` in the transaction but it's not saved to `fragmentNews` so you have two seperate Fragments it seems.

EDIT:

You could do it like this I think
Add this your Fragment:

```
@Override 
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState); 
    ((MainActivity) getActivity()).viewIsCreated();
}
```

And this in your activity

```
public void viewIsCreated() {
    ViewPager pager = fragmentNews.getPager();
    pager.setAdapter(pagerAdapter);
}
```

And remove those two lines from the `onCreate`

Comment: I fixed the lines with two separate fragments, it didn’t help. I also put this in fragment class:
`@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    isCreated = true;
}`
And in MainActivity.java:
`if (fragmentNews.isCreated) {

    
    ViewPager pager = fragmentNews.getPager();

    pager.setAdapter(pagerAdapter);

    ...
}`

But I even don’t reach the block inside `if`.

Answer (score 1):

Here

```
pager.setAdapter(pagerAdapter);
```

line causing issue because `pager` is `null`.

**Why?**

Because using two *different objects of `NewsFragment`* : one for calling `getPager` method another which is passing in  `add` method as last parameter.

Use same object which is passed in `add` method of accessing View's,methods,... from `NewsFragment` Fragment.

Comment: I fixed it: `fm.beginTransaction().add(R.id.container_for_fragments, fragmentNews).commit();` But still got error in pager.setAdapter(pagerAdapter); and pager == null

Comment: @alla: Probably `ViewPager pager = fragmentNews.getPager();` line is executing before call of `onCreateView ` method so try to use it `onResume` method or create a event listener which will fire from Fragment onViewCreated method in Activity when Views are fully loaded